# Vimeo embedded video custom controllers ( full sceen and volume control ) not working in media element js

Tags: javascript, html, flash, vimeo, mediaelement.js

I'm using media element js player for play you-tube and video embedded videos. 
Both videos are playing and but for vimeo custom controller bar fullscreen and volume control functions not working. 
Can I have any advice for this!

```
<video id="player2" width="640" height="360"  >
        <source type="video/vimeo" src="http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/45100844" /> 
</video>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#player2').mediaelementplayer({
                alwaysShowControls: true,
                success: function (media, node, player) {

                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

I'm using 'froogaloop2.min.js' for get vimeo controller bar

Comment: What you intend will *not* replace the default Vimeo player with the mediaelement.js player. It just allows to embed the default Vimeo player by using a HTML5 `<video>` tag. Source: tried it, and [this](http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/): "The Vimeo API wrapper […] will simply display the default Vimeo controls." Doing the same with YouTube videos will however use the mediaelement.js player – [example](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube).

Answer (score 1):

You must use this code

```
<video id="player2" width="640" height="360"  >
    <source type="video/vimeo" src="http://vimeo.com/45100844" /> 
</video>
```

including froogaloop2.min.js to show vimeo controller bar.

this works at my end. so it should work at your end, too.